# Basic Java Service class which implements

Tags: java

There is a base service interface with the following methods:

```
public interface BaseService {

    Dto convertToDto(Entity entity);
    List<Dto> convertToDtoList(List<Entity> entityList);
    Entity convertToEntity(Dto dto);
    List<Entity> convertToEntityList(List<Dto> dtoList);

}
```

Now the methods *convertToDtoList* and *convertToEntityList* should get implemented in a base service implementation which is then extended by other services so that these methods only have to be implemented once in the base service. Both *convertToDtoList* and *convertToEntityList* have always the same implementation except they are using the different entity and dto types of the respective service class:

```
public List<Dto> convertToDtoList(List<Entity> entityList) {
    if (entityList == null)
        return null;

    List<Dto> dtoList = new ArrayList<Dto>();
    Iterator<Entity> it = entityList.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
        dtoList.add(this.convertToDto(it.next()));

    return dtoList;
}


public List<Entity> convertToEntityList(List<Dto> dtoList) {
    if (dtoList == null)
        return null;

    List<Entity> entityList = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    Iterator<Dto> it = dtoList.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
        entityList.add(this.convertToEntity(it.next()));

    return entityList;
}
```

How can I implement these methods in the base service in a generic way abstracting from the respective entity and dto types so that I can use them in every service class which is extending this base service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default implementation in interface and template `<>`:

```
public interface BaseService<D, E> {

    D convertToDto(E entity);

    E convertToEntity(D dto);

    default List<E> convertToEntityList(List<D> dtoList) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(dtoList).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
                       .map(this::convertToEntity)
                       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    default List<D> convertToDtoList(List<E> entityList) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(entityList).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
                       .map(this::convertToDto)
                       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}

public class DtoEntityBaseService implements BaseService<Dto, Entity> {

    @Override
    public Dto convertToDto(Entity entity) {}

    @Override
    public Entity convertToEntity(Dto dto) {}
}
```

---

> You can look at very useful framework that help to do all these
>   transformation. It calls [Mapsruct](https://mapstruct.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
public interface BaseService <T> {

    Dto convertToDto(Entity entity);
    default public List<Dto> convertToDtoList(List<T> entityList) {
        if (entityList == null)
            return null;

        List<Dto> dtoList = new ArrayList<Dto>();
        Iterator<T> it = entityList.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext())
            dtoList.add(this.convertToDto(it.next()));

        return dtoList;
    }

    default public List<Entity> convertToEntityList(List<T> dtoList) {
        if (dtoList == null)
            return null;

        List<Entity> entityList = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        Iterator<T> it = dtoList.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext())
            entityList.add(this.convertToEntity(it.next()));

        return entityList;
    }
    Entity convertToEntity(Dto dto);
}
```

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) for more information.